# Cannot Manually Swipe Down Using Finger on Motion Layout After Adding setOnClickListener Code - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-motionlayout

I'm a beginner on using Motion Layout that using swipe effect. I want to create swiping effect on a view manually with finger that swiped down until it "disappear" like in Youtube video bottom layout (until 1 dp precisely) and it also can clicked to another activity. But after I add setOnClickListener code on my swiping view, swiping down manually using finger is not working and I still don't know how to handle it. I try to solve with many tutorials but it don't answer this solution.

Before adding setOnClickListener code on view :

[image]

After adding setOnClickListener code on view :

[image]

This is the motion layout code part :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_xml_constraintlayout_scene">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/motionLayoutExample"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:itemCount="20"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_rv" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/motionLayoutExample"
        layout="@layout/view_motion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/btn_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Where the include part is the swiping view area which I want to manually swipe down until "disappear" and also can click into another activity

This is the motion scene part from my motion layout :

```
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/motionTransitions"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
           <KeyAttribute
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/motionLayoutExample"
               motion:framePosition="100"
               android:alpha="0" />
           <KeyAttribute
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/motionLayoutExample"
               motion:framePosition="75"
               android:alpha="0.5" />
       </KeyFrameSet>
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/motionLayoutExample"
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="middle"
            motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="false"
            motion:nestedScrollFlags="disableScroll"
            motion:onTouchUp="decelerate"
            motion:touchRegionId="@id/motionLayoutExample"/>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end"
        android:alpha="0">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/motionLayoutExample"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavView"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerView"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

This is the setOnClickListener code that makes the view cannot swipe down manually using finger, only can click into another activity : (motionLayoutExample = findViewById(R.id.motionLayoutExample))

```
motionLayoutExample.setOnClickListener()
{
    Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).also()
    {
        startActivity(it)
    }
}
```

So, what should I do to make the view can swipe down manually using finger and clicked into another activity? (I don't know much about using Motion Layout technique)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something google should fix in their next update , meanwhile try using the

```
onClick="@function"
```

tag in the XML file and call the Activity's function here in the XML file.

Comment: Didn't work . I try using it, but it still the same :(